# What is the Z thickness of a 2D (X,Y) plane that is instantly transported into a 3D space?

Tags: geometry

Assuming I had a two-dimensional clipped plane having size $(1.0, 1.0)$ along $(X,Y)$; what would the $Z$ value become if this plane were transported, instantly, into a three-dimensional world?

I understand the realistic answers to this would be implementation-dependent (operating system, language, compiler, etc.); however, I'm interested in a purely-theoretical discussion.

Comment: Assuming this is an abstract plane, rather than a plane made of some physical material like plastic or wood, the thickness would obviously be zero.  What else could it be?

Comment: You are correct-- this would be an abstract plane. If you feel confident that zero is the correct answer, go ahead and answer the question. A list of other possibilities could include infinitely thin/thick, undefined, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be zero.  There's nothing mysterious about embedding a $2$-dimensional plane in a $3$-dimensional space; the set of solutions to an equation of the form $Ax+By+Cz=D$ (where $A, B, C$, and $D$ are real numbers, with at least one of $A, B, C$ nonzero) is a plane, and the thickness of such a plane can't be described as anything other than zero.

Comment: So, then, the plane would be infinitely thin UNTIL it's formally assigned a third dimension, at which point its third dimension would be initialized to zero; however, if it existed only with properties of area and never gained thickness, even in three-dimensional space, its thinness would remain infinite?

Comment: What does "infinitely thin" even mean?  Unless you are working in some form of nonstandard analysis, there are no infinitely small positive numbers; "infinitely thin" is just "zero thickness".  And I'm not sure what you mean by "assigned" and "initialized"; you seem to be thinking about some kind of software context that you haven't made clear.

Comment: Sorry, "initialize" is an English language word that means (from Google) "set to the value or put in the condition appropriate to the start of an operation."; as far as infinite thinness, I found this definition for "line" (from http://www.mathopenref.com/coordline.html): "A geometrical object that is straight, infinitely long and infinitely thin..."

Comment: I know what "initialize" means, but I don't understand what you mean by it.  You wrote in your original question about "operating system, language, compiler, etc." -- which suggests that you are thinking about this as some kind of code that gets executed.  If so, I think we need to know more about the context you have in mind.

Comment: Regarding "infinitely thin", it isn't *meaningless*, exactly, but it doesn't mean anything *different from* "zero".

Comment: No context implied by initialize-- it was just the word my mind was trained to use. Also, I'm willing to accept your assertion that [infinitely thin] doesn't mean anything different from "zero".